# Using an index with ng-table over multiple pages

Tags: html, angularjs, ngtable

I am using ng-table to display the below data.

I want the first column to be an index number that persists over pages (eg page with rows 100-199 should have index 100-199).

Currently the index resets and starts at 0 every page. I have also tried

```
{{ (FarmParams.page() * FarmParams.count()) + index }}
```

but the first page will start at index 100 in this case.

```
<table ng-table="vm.FarmParams" class="table table-hover">
<tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
    <td data-title="''" filter="{index : 'text'}" sortable="'index'">{{$index}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Planted:'" filter="{planted : 'text'}" sortable="'planted'">{{row.planted}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Harvested'" filter="{harvested: 'text'}" sortable="'harvested'">{{row.harvested}} </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could subtract one from the page then.

```
{{ ((FarmParams.page() - 1) * FarmParams.count()) + index }}
```

Comment: Thanks I should have seen that.

Comment: Where the `index` comes from? it is undefined. It seems there is no build-in index related property in the row but need to use the $index of ng-repeat. But the the problem of isolated scope comes, and I end up with adding a `index` property in each row to record the ng-repeat $index by `ng-init="row.index=$index"` in the `<tr>` tag, for the future reference.